# Resize layout on soft keyboard appearance in KitKat immersive mode

Tags: android, android-layout, android-4.4-kitkat, window-resize

Ran into a bit of an issue when implementing immersion mode on my KitKat messaging app.

When setting the immersive mode, I find that my app no longer resizes when the soft keyboard is displayed, despite having the "adjustresize=true" attribute in the manifest.

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

I read even further to discover that when immersive mode is triggered, it also sets a flag for fullscreen mode, and in Android, fullscreen mode apps ignore any resizing to the view since they are supposed to be fullscreen and never resize.

This would be the end to my problem, but I discovered another app that uses immersive mode on KitKat, and is also capable of resizing the layout when the soft keyboard appears. See here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.klinker.android.evolve_sms&hl=en. I'm wondering what tricks they implemented to keep the window resize feature along side the wonderful fullscreen immersion mode.

Comment: That app uses the translucent decor theme not the immersive mode.

Comment: Hi! Have you find a solution?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, and it seems like it's an old bug that hasn't been fixed yet. I am currently experimenting to find some kind of workaround -like resizing the activity manually when the keyboard is triggered.

Comment: If you can manage with translucent decor instead of immersive mode, the resize will happen if for the parent layout, you've set `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`